# convert gmt to local timezone in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, dst

I have a gmt timestamp and I need to convert it into a local timezone (**taking into account daylight saving**).

do you know how to do that in pandas? 
thanks!

Comment: what is `type(your_gmt_timestamp)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tz_localize` is a possible candidate.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html

Comment: @JFSebastian the timestamp look like this 
01 JAN 2005 03:04:55.670 . What would be the approriate command to convert this into a local Paris time that takes into account daylight saving?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian actually ;-)