# How do I best adjust a timestamp with a timezone in python?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I need to operate on dates within my pandas dataframe but my code has a bug.  Specifically I am importing a column of timestamps from a csv file.

```
x['Created at']
0       2016-05-13 13:28:41 -0400
1       2016-05-13 05:11:18 -0400
3       2016-05-12 18:06:42 -0400
4       2016-05-12 16:06:24 -0400
5       2016-05-12 13:58:01 -0400
6       2016-05-12 03:30:27 -0400
```

I am then changing this data into a datetime.  I am doing this via `pandas.to_datetime(df['date'])` but when I do this, the time is getting shifted by 4 hours.

```
x.Createdat
0      2016-05-13 17:28:41
1      2016-05-13 09:11:18
3      2016-05-12 22:06:42
4      2016-05-12 20:06:24
5      2016-05-12 17:58:01
6      2016-05-12 07:30:27
```

I am assuming this is because of the `-0400` at the end of the timestamp but I can not figure out the best way to resolve this issue so I can aggregate this data in my own timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the -400 is information that you do not need or want, then simply change your use of `pandas.to_datetime(df['date'])` to  `pandas.to_datetime(df['date'].apply(lambda x: x[:-6])` which will drop the -400 from the string. Not the best and most robust approach, but it will work.

If you want to use the -400 but you want to convert it to a different timezone, check out `tz_localize` as described in this answer: [convert gmt to local timezone in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584500/convert-gmt-to-local-timezone-in-pandas)

Another tool that should help is using `pytz`: [pytz - Converting UTC and timezone to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264811/pytz-converting-utc-and-timezone-to-local-time)